# Calculate percentage of element in column within groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hello everyone I woule need help in order to count the percentage of values within columns and groups.
Here is an exempel dataframe

```
       Groups COL1
0      G1  DOG
1      G1  DOG
2      G1  DOG
3      G1  CAT
4      G2  CAT
5      G2  DOG
6      G3  DOG
7      G3  CAT
8      G3  CAT
9      G3  CAT
10     G3  CAT
11     G4  DOG
12     G4  DOG
```

and I would like to only keep Groups where the percentage of `DOG` `>= 50%`

so here for instance :

```
G1 = 3/4 = 75% I keep this group
G2 = 1/2 = 50% I remove this group
G3 = 1/5 = 20% I remove this group 
G4 = 2/2 = 100% I keep this groups
```

Then I should get

```
   Groups COL1
0      G1  DOG
1      G1  DOG
2      G1  DOG
3      G1  CAT
11     G4  DOG
12     G4  DOG
```

does someone have an idea please ?

here is the dataframe in dict format if it can helps:

```
{'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G1', 4: 'G2', 5: 'G2', 6: 'G3', 7: 'G3', 8: 'G3', 9: 'G3', 10: 'G3', 11: 'G4', 12: 'G4'}, 'COL1': {0: 'DOG', 1: 'DOG', 2: 'DOG', 3: 'CAT', 4: 'CAT', 5: 'DOG', 6: 'DOG', 7: 'CAT', 8: 'CAT', 9: 'CAT', 10: 'CAT', 11: 'DOG', 12: 'DOG'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `mean` of boolean mask for compared `DOG` and filter by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['COL1'].eq('DOG').groupby(df['Groups']).transform('mean').gt(0.5)]
print (df)
   Groups COL1
0      G1  DOG
1      G1  DOG
2      G1  DOG
3      G1  CAT
11     G4  DOG
12     G4  DOG
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! and what if I also whant to add another value such as ```HORSE``` ? can I use ```df[df['COL1'].eq('DOG|HORSE').groupby(df['Groups']).transform('mean').gt(0.5)]```

Comment: @chippycentra - then use `isin` like `df[df['COL1'].isin(['DOG', 'HORSE']).groupby(df['Groups']).transform('mean').gt(0.5)]`